# Force specific interface when instantiating an object

Tags: c#, inheritance, wrapper

I am working with a library that gives me access to a remote machine.

This library is out since at least 10 years, and over time they added to it multiple fetures to several objects; in order to do so without breaking compatibility (at least this is what I think) they have designed multiple interfaces, that are implemented like this:

```
//Version 1.0:
interface First
{
    void AMethod();
}

//Version 1.1:
interface Second : First
{
    void AMethod();
    void AnotherMethod();
}

//Version 1.2:
interface Third : Second
{
    void AMethod();
    void AnotherMethod();
    void AlsoAnotherMethod();
}

//Version 1.3:
interface Fourth : Third
{
    void AMethod();
    void AnotherMethod();
    void AlsoAnotherMethod();
    void EvenMoreMethod();
}
------------------------------------------------------------

//Version 1.3:
public InterfaceImplementor : Fourth
{
    //code that do stuff
}
```

The problem is that now I have to connect to a machine that is really old, and using the object as is return a "unexpected error", that doesn't give me any information for debugging.

So, I was thinking: 
Is it possible to force an object to implement a specific interface along the dependancy/inheritance tree? This should be possible, as every interface  redefines every method (of course, if I choose to implement the `First` interface, then I would be able to use only the `AMethod()` ), am I correct?

I cannot change the interfaces nor derive a new object from the `First` interface, as this is a C# wrap for a c++ library that contains Who-knows-what, and apparently it needs more than just a simple `NewObject : First`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Only the AMethod would be defined in the first interface. I'm not sure I exactly understand why you might want to do this. Excessive inheritance is usually a bad thing. If you use this kind of structure with generics you can require your T to implement an interface.

Comment: If it is a COM component operated through remoting, you may try simply casting it to one of older interfaces, that is `var remote=(First)CreateRemoteObject();`

Comment: On the other hand, the wrapper itself may do the cast inside, and then that cast may fail regardless of your cast. If that's the case - look for the old versions of the wrapper or write one yourself (you can reference C++ IJW libs in C# just like any other lib).